# Windows Forms Application C#: adding global variables:

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

Good day, 
I am trying to make a windows forms application that requires connectivity to one of our databases.

I can get connected to the database with System.Data.Odbc objects.

I have no problem creating OdbcConnection objects in local functions, opening it, reading data and closing it. However my forms requires many queries to be sent, therefore I want to avoid opening and closing a connection every time I want to query the database.

now, the approach I wanted to take was to declare an OdbcConnection object as a field of my Forms class, then open it in the InitializeComponent() method, let the database connection be open for the duration of the Form, and close it only when the form is closing.

But that is a problem because Visual Studio doesnt want to let me modify anything in InitializeComponent(), everything there has to be created by the Form design on my behalf, so I can't open the OdbcConnection myself.

What is the clean way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using `Command` and `Connection` objects It's better to open and close connection yourself. If you are using `DataAdapter`, you can let the adapter control state of connection.

Comment: Define a specific class to do this, and apply/use the singleton pattern. Read more here: [link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: @Maarten I think sharing a connection is not a good idea. `ADO.Net` will do it using connection pooling if required. But if the OP wants to perform not such a good job, using singleton is a good offer.

Comment: thank you for the replies. Actually I noticed as long as I don't modify the InitializeComponent() method, Visual Studio wont complain if I add private fields at the end of Form1.Designer.cs, so right now I have an on load event handler opening the OdbcConnection instance, and a FormClosing event handler closing it. are there any pitfalls with my approach?

Comment: Don't touch `Form1.Designer.cs`, instead add a property to `Form1.cs`

Comment: ok thanks. also should I do my dirty work in the constructor before/after calling InitializeComponent, or keep it OnLoad event handler?

Comment: Reza thanks I would actually appreciate that. right now I have kept both event handlers for opening and closing the form. I declared a private field OdbcConnection conn (not a property yet) in Form1.cs . I go ahead and open it in the load event handler. I can query the database all I want and I make sure to close it with the closing event handler. please do let me know if opening the connection in Form1 constructor is better practice than onLoad event handler.

Comment: yes thanks. I had similar implementation. with the difference that I had private Load and Close event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Command` objects It's better to open and close connection yourself. If you are using `DataAdapter`, you can let the adapter control state of connection.

You should know Sharing a connection is not a good idea. ADO.Net will do it using connection pooling if required and I recommend you to open and close connections manually.

But based on your request here is the code you can use:

```
public class Form1:Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitiallizeComponent();
    }

    private OdbcConnection connection;

    //If you want to open and close connection automatically uncomment commented codes
    //Then you don't need to open and close connection manually
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        connection= new OdbcConnection("your connection string here");
        //this.Connection.Open();
        base.OnLoad();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Connection.Close();
        this.Connection.Dispose();         
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just write

```
    public partial class credentials : Form
    {
    private Connection con;

        public credentials()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            con = new Connection();
        }
}
```

Comment: good call, I tried it and it worked. I was afraid of Visual Studio complaining if I mess with the constructor, but it turns out it only complains if I mess with InitializeComponent();